# Rational Points, classical versus modern notion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In classical algebraic geometry, a $\mathbb Q$-rational point on a, say, complex affine variety $V\subseteq\mathbb C^n$ is a point $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ with $\forall i: p_i\in\mathbb Q$. Now, in modern language, a $\mathbb Q$-rational point is a morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Q)\to V$. Clearly, if $V$ is defined as $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I)$, then $V$ *has* no $\mathbb Q$-rational points in this language. Of course, if $I$ is generated by polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$, we could look at  $V_{\mathbb Q}=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Q[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I)$ so $V=V_{\mathbb Q}\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Q)}\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C)$ and the classically $\mathbb Q$-rational points are the $\mathbb Q$-rational points of $V_{\mathbb Q}$. However, the object $V_{\mathbb Q}$ now fails to capture all classically $\mathbb C$-rational points. For instance, the scheme $V_{\mathbb Q}=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x(x^2+1)\rangle)$ contains two points, one of which is $\mathbb Q$-rational. However, base-changing it to $\mathbb C$, we get $3$ points, none of which is $\mathbb Q$-rational.

This is somewhat unsatisfactory to me. The classical definition seems so straightforward and clean, and I have a single object $V$ containing all my $\mathbb C$-rational points while it is still possible to easily identify the $\mathbb Q$-rational points. Unfortunately, the usual textbooks don't really elaborate on the merits of modern language with regard to this particular aspect. I would be very grateful if someone could do so.

I guess my question should be phrased as follows: Given a scheme $V$ defined over $\mathbb C$, what is the correct way, in modern language, to identify what I would classically consider to be the $\mathbb Q$-rational points in $V$?

Comment: You might be able to do this for $\mathbb{Q}$, but only because it's the prime field. I doubt you would be able to identify, say, the $\mathbb{R}$-rational points without first choosing an embedding into affine space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $V\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a complex subvariety, the fact that $V$ has a rational point really depends on the embedding (Take the line $X=0$ and the line $X=\pi$ in a plane).

Thus, the question is whether $V$ has a $\mathbb{C}$-point which happen to lie over a $\mathbb{Q}$-point of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

In other words, you are looking for commutative diagrams
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}Spec\mathbb{C} @>>> Spec\mathbb{Q}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
V @>>> \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^n
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that's a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be a Galois extension of $K$ and $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$. Let $X$ be a $K$-scheme. Then $G$ acts on the set $X(L)$ of $K$-morphisms $\mathrm{Spec}(L) \to X$, and $X(L)^G = X(K)$. So maybe one should take Galois invariants to define rational points?

I think it is also true that $X_L(L) = X(L)$, where $X_L = X \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(K)} \mathrm{Spec}(L)$ and $X_L(L)$ is the set of $L$-morphisms $\mathrm{Spec}(L) \to X_L$, but it seems somehow harder to see the Galois action on $X_L(L)$ since everything here is living over $L$ rather than over $K$, so it's hard to figure out which of its elements should be called $K$-rational.

For example, with $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x(x^2+1))$ like in your question, there are three $\mathbb{Q}$-morphisms $\mathrm{Spec}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}) \to X$, which means three elements in $X(\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$. The absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$ fixes only one of them since conjugation interchanges the other two, so we're able to pick out the rational point by taking Galois invariants.

**Edit**. Two things. First thing is that in general, one doesn't really need $L$ to be Galois over $K$. An $L$-point of a $K$-scheme $X$ is just a point $x \in X$ and an embedding $\kappa(x) \hookrightarrow L$ of the residue field $\kappa(x)$ of $x$ into $L$. It's a $K$-point if this embedding factors through $K$. Equivalently, amongst the elements of $X(L)$, the $K$-points are the ones in the image of the map $X(K) \to X(L)$ induced by the inclusion $K \hookrightarrow L$. Then, when $L$ is Galois over $K$, one can recover this image by taking Galois invariants.

Second thing. I think it might be too much to hope for to identify the $K$-points of an $L$-scheme without somehow remembering that the $L$-scheme came from a $K$-scheme to begin with? Namely, I think if there were a way of doing it, it wouldn't be an isomorphism invariant on the category of $L$-schemes. For example, with $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x(x^2+1)))$, notice that $X_{\bar{\mathbb{Q}}}$ is isomorphic as a $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$-scheme to $Y = \mathrm{Spec}(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}[x]/(x(x^2-1)))$, with the isomorphism given by $x \mapsto ix$ on the level of $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$-algebras.

Comment: The problem with this is that I'd like to start with an $L$-scheme in the first place, not with a $K$-scheme.